# Improving hips mobility

Tags: hip, mobility

I had sex recently (for the first time) and, despite of working out regularly, it has been physically demanding (I was forced to use a towel after only few minutes, in order to dry my forehead).

Although my partner was very helpful/supportive, moving my hips was not fluid, exhausting.

I usually do a lot of cardio, heavy weight lifting (80 kg deadlift, 40 kg deadlift, 15 kg snatch), a bit of yoga (including hip-opening sequences). I'm working on my anterior-pelvic tilt for 2 years now.

Is there exercises/workout helping to gain in hips mobility?

Comment: Not entirely sure this is a good fit for the exchange, but just as an aside, everything takes practice. Nobody is smooth the first time at anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have more sex for longer.

There's no real exercise to mimic it because it's a two people thing.

Probably the closest you'll get is push ups in a sauna to get used to the high temperature.